# How do I skip scanning the disk upon boot in Windows?

Tags: windows, chkdsk

I ran CHKDSK /R/F and now it always tries to scan the disk when I boot. I want to skip that scan. But it says press any key within zero seconds to skip the scan and then immediately starts scanning. Even if I hold down F8 then it still continues the scan.  I have to turn off the computer and turn it back on again  repeatedly.

Comment: What if you let it scan the disk *once*?

Comment: Let it scan every boot up until it stops asking; keep rebooting until it does. There's a flag that will clear itself once the disk is 'fixed' & not before. One scan is not always enough. Switching it off & on again whilst it's trying to do this will inevitably lead to more damage.

Comment: @grawity It takes like 5-8 hours! Ain't no one got time for that! I get it, the disk is bad. I want to get back in and do what little work I can until my new disk comes.